# How to use the one database table to another database stored procedure, dynamically pass the database name

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, asp.net-4.0

Now I am using one database table to another database stored procedure normally (`database name..table name`) but I have dynamically pass the database name how to write the stored procedure pls give me any suggestion

I am writing like this

```
Select QT.Name,SC.Name as Status,QT.QuoteNumber,QT.PolicyNumber,LC.Name as LineCode,QT.DBAName as DBAName       
  from QMSV3Dev..Quote QT, QMSV3Dev..StatusCode SC, QMSV3Dev..LineCode LC      
  where QT.StatusCode = SC.StatusCode And QT.LineCode = LC.LineCode and       
  QT.DBAName like 'a%' order by QT.Name,QuoteNumber desc
```

In above stored procedure `QMSV3Dev..Quote`, `QMSV3Dev` is the database name and `Quote` is table name, this sp executed in another database like `test` now

Same query pass the database name dynamically

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[usp_GetSearch123]      
(      
 @SearchValue varchar(100),      
 @SearchBy varchar(250),
 @DbName varchar(50)      
)     
AS    
Begin
  Select QT.Name,SC.Name as Status,QT.QuoteNumber,QT.PolicyNumber,LC.Name as LineCode,QT.DBAName as DBAName         
  from  @DbName+'..Quote ' QT,@DbName+'.. StatusCode' SC, @DbName+'..Linecodes' LC      
  where QT.StatusCode = SC.StatusCode And QT.LineCode = LC.LineCode and       
  (QT.Name like @SearchValue+'%' or QT.DBAName like @SearchValue+'%')       
  order by QT.Name,QuoteNumber desc
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simpler that you think. For that, you have to use [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

It would be something like this:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[usp_GetSearch123]      
(      
 @SearchValue varchar(100),      
 @SearchBy varchar(250),
 @DbName varchar(50)      
)     
AS    
Begin

  Declare @cmd varchar(5000)

  select @cmd = 
  'Select QT.Name,SC.Name as Status,QT.QuoteNumber,QT.PolicyNumber,LC.Name as LineCode,QT.DBAName as DBAName         
  from ' + @DbName + '..Quote QT, ' + @DbName + '.. StatusCode SC, ' + @DbName+'..Linecodes LC      
  where QT.StatusCode = SC.StatusCode And QT.LineCode = LC.LineCode and       
  (QT.Name like "' + @SearchValue + '%" or QT.DBAName like "' + @SearchValue +'%")       
  order by QT.Name,QuoteNumber desc'

  exec(@cmd)
 end
```

---

You create a `varchar` variable `@cmd` and put the select on it and afterwards execute it by `exec(@cmd)`.

Comment: it is not working error is    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_GetSearch123, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'QT'.

Comment: created successfully but in execution exec usp_GetSearch123 'a','','QMSV3Dev' error is Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'QMSV3Dev..StatusCodes'. pls check it

Comment: @hmkmudiam is there a table StatusCodes in database QMSV3Dev? Is there a database QMSV3Dev? By your code it seems the table is StatusCode. I've changed it, try again.